# Problems with daemon syncing past block 1341326

Tags: monerod, synchronization, daemon, monerod-commands

I just noticed that my daemon has not been able to sync past block 1341326. A little investigation shows my node reporting that I'm behind by so many blocks, and then randomly it will say that I'm so many blocks ahead.

Question - when it reports that I'm ahead, is that just because someone who is further behind is still syncing up? Or is there something else going on with peers who are that far behind, (and yet somehow are telling me I'm ahead)?

I do see an error popping up which appears to be related to a network service or something but I'm not sure if it's related. I can connect to the internet just fine as I'm writing this post from the same machine where monerod is.

The error I see is this.

2017-Jul-10 09:40:04.660681 [P2P6]ERROR /DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/contrib/epee/include/net/abstract_tcp_server2.inl:1061 Exception at [boosted_tcp_server::connect], what=resolve: Service not found

Should I just blow away my current install and install fresh or are there some commands that might get me past this?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you're on an old release. The current version (v0.10.3.1) doesn't bounce around like that on reporting sync state any more.

Comment: Awesome thanks hyc - that was the problem. I was running monerod out of the wrong directory - I still have 10.1 around and apparently cd'd to it instead of 10.3.1.

Comment: Did you get any message in the daemon telling you you should update ?